# service data should not remove , while refresh the page using angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

- I have two separate page controller then  assign the data on  service in first controller . That service data i can use from second controller(another page ) But if refresh the page(second controller page) , that service data displaying  as undefined

  //  **Controller 1**

  ```
  app.controller("pageCtrl",['$scope','pojo' , function( $scope,pojo)
  {

    pojo.setpgeCtrlScope($scope);

  }
  ]);
  ```

  //   **Controller 2**

  ```
  app.controller("pageCtrl2",['$scope','pojo' , function( $scope,pojo)
  {

   pojo.getpgeCtrlScope();

  }
  ]);
  ```

  //   **pojo service**

  ```
  app.service("pojo",function()
  {
    var page1Data;
    this.setpgeCtrlScope = function(data)
    {
      page1Data = data;
     }
    this.setpgeCtrlScope = function()
    {
      return page1Data;
    };
  });
  ```

Please give the suggestion  for above problem. any other way to pass the data to 2nd controller . and that one should not remove while refresh the page

```
      Thank you !!
```

Comment: what does it mean by page refresh, show the url before and after

Answer (score 1):

This data is in memory. If you refresh the page you will loose it.

You can use some approaches, like storing the data in your service in a cache, local storage, etc.

For example:

```
app.service("pojo", function() {
    var page1Data = getSavedData(); //A method to retrieve the data from a cache or storage
    this.setpgeCtrlScope = function(data) {
        page1Data = data;
        saveData(page1Data); //A method to save the data to the cache or storage
    }
    this.getpgeCtrlScope = function() {
        return page1Data;
    };
});
```

This way everytime the service is loaded (after a page refresh) it's going to retrieve the data previously saved.

Regarding the storage, there are a lot of options. This one is really easy to use:
[HTML5 Local Storate](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

There are a myriad solutions and implementations for this. I gave you only one example to guide you.

Comment: Thank you , denisazevedo, i have another one doubt . if cleared cache ,it'll work . ..? i mean localstorage will work ?

Comment: It depends. [Chrome implements it like _cache_](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideHtml5Storage) and [Mozilla like _cookies_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage). So, for example, if you clear the cache in Chrome, your localstorage should be cleared too. This is also a good read: [DOM Storage from John Resig's Blog](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-storage/)